# Error when getting data in Excel from Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a SQL statement2 from another SQL statement1, columns are the same and values. the only difference is that each of the tables takes information from different tables.
I want that the query output is in excel. The output from statement1 is shown in excel perfectly, however from statement 2 I got an error `The error message ODBC driver does not support the requested properties`

Could you figure out where it comes from, seems that some function ODBC driver does not support in my query?

Statement2:

```
select *
from (
select 
  quantity,
    case 
    when HOURFLAG=1 and whathour_UTC >= 0 and whathour_UTC < 21  then DATETIME + interval '1' hour  else TIME end as TIME,
   STARTTIME,
   whathour_UTC,
  case 
    when HOURFLAG=1 and whathour_UTC >= 0 then concat('H',TO_CHAR(DATETIME,'HH24')+1) 
    else concat('H',TO_CHAR(TIME,'HH24')+0) 
    end as whathour --+0 
from (

select 
  amount as quantity,
  DATA_DTTM,
  FROM_TZ(CAST(TIME AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') at time zone 'Europe/Berlin' as DATETIME,
  to_char(cast(TIME AS TIMESTAMP), 'HH24')+0 as whathour_UTC,
  TRUNC(FROM_TZ(CAST(TIME AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') at time zone 'Europe/Helsinki','DAY') as STARTTIME,
   HOURFLAG
from 
  MYDB
 ) b ) c
where 
  whathour <> 'H24' 
ORDER BY 
  METERING_POINT_EIC,PRODCONS,DATETIME
```

Comment: In your first `CASE WHEN` statement you have missed the comma, it could be at least one reason.

Comment: I updated the question, it was a typo.

Comment: Why don't you try with some simple query to see if the error is on your query or in your odbc connector?